# d3 transition overlap causing odd behaviour

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filter, transition

Hovering over a node in the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upMb5/) causes all other nodes and links to fade out except for the link connected to the hovered node.

This works as intended if you move the mouse from one node to another slowly.
However if you move the mouse too fast the link connected to the current node stays faded.

Why is this happening? My intent is to always have the hovered node and connected link visible.

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) { 
    svg.selectAll(".node").filter(function(other) { 
        return (other.name != d.name);
    }) 
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .style('opacity', 0.1);

    svg.selectAll(".link")
        .transition()
        .filter(function(other) {
            return (other.source.name != d.name) && (other.target.name != d.name);
        }) 
        .duration(750)
        .style('opacity', 0.1);
})

.on("mouseout", function(d){ 
    svg.selectAll(".node, .link")
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .style('opacity', 1.0);
});
```

Comment: The earlier transitions are simply superseded by the later transitions. In Chrome, this doesn't cause a problem though -- at some point, the correct nodes will be shown. What browser are you using?

Comment: Are you sure about that? I'm using Chrome and the link never becomes fully opaque.

Comment: Yes, works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is calling `transition()`, then `filter()`. If you first filter, and then trigger  transition, the problem is gone! [link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6u8u/)

[image]

Comment: This fixed my problem also. Thank you for figuring this out.